# Multiple NFT tracking ARToolkit iOS

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I am trying to create an ARToolKit app in iOS with multiple NFTs.
I have generated the featured set(.fset) and image set(.iset) of both the images, edited the markers.dat file as well.

When I try to scan the images, it displays the object only on one image, on the image which is declared first in the markers.dat file. If i change the order of declaration of the images then the object is displayed on only the second image(which was declared first in the markers.dat file).

Is this some kind of bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look here:
https://github.com/artoolkit/artoolkit5/issues/115#issuecomment-217771991

There I listed all the steps that you need to check if you want to have multiple NFT working. I did this for an Android example but it should be the same for iOS.
Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks alot man :)
I didn't put the extra object.The explanation is really good and the screenshots were also very helpful.

Also can you please help me if i want to remove the 3D Models and want just plain text instead of it.
Thanks agin :)

Comment: Hi good to hear that the answer is helpful. Can you please mark the answer as solution so that others can find it too.

Comment: Regarding the 3D models and the text. Please open another question.